# What's the correct way set a Text to secondary text color from theme in 2023?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Android, I can simply do:

```java
@ColorInt val secondaryColor = MaterialColors.getColor(context, android.R.attr.textColorSecondary, Color.BLACK)
```

What's the equivalanet in flutter? I don't seem to find a solution like that after googling.

Comment: Perhaps the question will be `on version:x,x,x` instead of `theme in 2023?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
var secondaryColor = Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor;
```

can use it in your code, like:

```
 Text('hello world', style: TextStyle(
            color: secondaryColor,
          ),)
```